# Working with associate array in javascript

Tags: javascript

I making one application which contains 2 input box and one input button.My qestion is when user enter some input eg. "I used to  going somewhere" then my result should be              "I UD GNG somewhere." For that i am using this code  http://pastebin.com/vHkhASdZ

Please,anyone have idea how to solve then pls  reply me asap. I solved my issue in php but in case of javascript i don't have any idea. Here is my output link in php http://codepad.viper-7.com/SQvO6Y
I want my result in javascript.Pls anyone know then give reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this function

```
var replaceText = function () {
    var inputval = document.getElementById('first_text').value;
    var arr = {
        "going": "GNG",
        "used to": "UD",
        "as soon as possible": "ASAP",
        "to do fast": "tdf"
    }

    for(var key in arr) {
        if (typeof (arr[key]) !== "undefined") inputval = inputval.replace(key, arr[key])
    }
    document.getElementById("second_text").value = inputval;
}
```

Comment: Dear sir,http://jsfiddle.net/sandeeppandey350/Q6ttQ/ i tried this but not getting any solution.  pls suggest me where i doing wrong.

Comment: Why the undefined test? You're not going to get an undefined in a for..in loop (unless you've explicitly assigned a key to undefined).

Comment: @nnnnnn Sorry my bad, it should be `if(arr.hasOwnProperty(key))`. This ables to determine whether an object has the specified property as a direct property of `arr` object

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this. Define word replace as map.

```
var wordmap = {
  going: 'GNG',
  'used to': 'UD',
  'as soon as possible': 'asap',
  'to do fast': 'tdf',
  ..
```

}

and define function that iterates every word in the input string.

```
function replace( text ) {
    var input = text.split(' ');
    var outputval = []
    for (var i in input) {
       outputval.push( wordmap[input[i]] || input[i] )
    }
    return outputval.join(' ');
}
```

And use it like this

```
var output = replace( document.getElementById('first_text').value );
```

Comment: Dear sir, http://jsfiddle.net/sandeeppandey350/M5aNm/ i tried this but not getting any solution.